# List comprehension in relation to biology

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to write a function using list comprehension about open reading frame using a dictionary of only the stop codon. The program takes in three letter at a time and if that three letter is one of that stop codon, the program stops and counts the number of letters (the stop codon is NOT counted, nor is anything afterwards).

For example, `nextStop2('AAAAAAAGTGGGTGCTAGGTTGGC')` should return 15. Here is what I have so far but python keeps telling me syntax error. Can anyone give me any advice on how to improve?

```
def nextStop2(Seq):
    GeneticCodeStop = {'TAA':'X', 'TAG':'X', 'TGA':'X'}
    seq2 = ''.join(i if GeneticCodeStop[Seq[i:i+3]]!='X' else end_of_loop() 
                   for i in range(0,len(Seq),3))
    return len(seq2)
```

A correct code using simply for loop would be below (provided by diggusbickus). I tried to convert it into list comprehension but wasn't sure about the syntax.

```
def nextStop2(Seq):
    GeneticCodeStop = ['TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA']
    seq2=''
    for i in range(0,len(Seq),3) :
        codon=Seq[i:i+3]
        if codon in GeneticCodeStop:
            break
        seq2+=codon
    return len(seq2)
```

Comment: `i` is an integer. You can't join a list of integers, it has to be a list of strings.

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of line 4

Comment: But I think you want to join the codons, not the indexes.

Comment: Silly me, I forgot that syntax errors posted here are *always* a missing `)`.

Comment: The premise of list comprehensions is that they iterate full input. Here it's semantically more similar to a while loop.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for your comments. yes i also realized I'm joining a list of integers. but i wonder - how do I make them codons (strings) instead?

Comment: FYI, https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ exists. (This question is fine for Stack Overflow but you may find it useful later.)

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) (read comments bottom up):

```
''.join(  # joining them into a single string
    itertools.takewhile(
        lambda x: x not in GeneticCodeStop, # until a stop codon found
        (Seq[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(Seq), 3))  # iterate codons
    )
)
```

Comment: Why `join` at all? Why not `sum(3 for _ in [takewhile code])`

Comment: hi marat, thank you for your answer. is it possible for me to use the for loop only?

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp it's not clear if OP wants length or actual string. From comments: "i wonder - how do I make them codons (strings) instead?"

Comment: @xinhwa I don't see how `for` loop alone will make it, without abusing language syntax

Comment: gotcha! i want the length but thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Marat's answer. Returns the length of the string without allocating space for a copy:

```py
def nextStop2(Seq, GeneticCodeStop=['TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA']):
    return sum(3 for _ in
        itertools.takewhile(
            lambda x: x not in GeneticCodeStop,
            (Seq[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(Seq), 3))
        ))
```

Comment: do you think it's possible to do this with list comprehension using for loop only?

Comment: It may be possible, but I'd expect it to be a slower solution and require more memory -- what necessitates the list-comprehension part?